# How can I use Outlook 2007 to connect to mail service using active sync protocol

Tags: microsoft-outlook, lotus-notes, activesync

Has anyone tried connecting Outlook (Running Outlook 2007 on Windows 7) to a mail service using the [Microsoft Exchange Active Sync](http://technet.Microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/bb288524.aspx) protocol?  If so, how did you do it?

Wouldn't this solution probably eliminate the need for all the hacks/APIs needed to connect outlook to 'X' mail (Gmail, notes, etc)?

I know it is intended for mobile devices, but to me it looks like it is becoming the latest 'de facto' mail protocol for email/calendar/contact syncing due to the iPhone's support for it.

Comment: So what's the real question?!?

Comment: I clarified and removed some unnecessary verbage

Comment: Are you using DAMO for Lotus Notes? V8 and later supports Outlook 2007.

Comment: No we are not using DAMO.  I have looked into it but it needs to be installed on the domino server(also looks like it will be phased out by IBM).  I really just wanted to know if anyone as used Active Sync as a way to get mail on a desktop, in my case with outlook.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Microsoft Active Sync protocol is now supported by Outlook 2013.

See the preview feature list here:

http://www.microsoft.com/office/preview/en/outlook-2013-preview

Comment: Adding more context and a reference link to this would make it a much better answer.

Comment: Added a link to the feature reference for outlook 2013

Comment: It's still only a link. If that URL changes the answer will be useless. Please summarise the important bit of the answer here.

Answer (score 0):

**DISCLAIMER: THIS ANSWER CONTAINS MY OPINION AND SOME FACTS**

> but to me it looks like it is becoming the latest 'de facto' mail protocol for email/calendar/contact sync'ing due to the iPhone's support for it.

Not really, the 'de facto' mail protocol is the MSMAPI protocol for Exchange. I would argue that for mail/calendar/contacting syncing this is the most used protocol. Also implementing it depends on Microsoft licensing it to you. Just because Apple can do it doesn't mean you can too.

For mobile devices I would think that ActiveSync and Blackberry SRP are the two most popular 'standards'

For external users, you want to use Outlook Anywhere or Outlook RPC/HTTP.

As for getting Lotus Notes into Outlook, [use the connector](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=8ebbba59-5f17-4e52-8980-c4f0dfa92d65&displaylang=en).

> This solution would probably eliminate the need for all the hacks needed to connect outlook to 'X' mail (Gmail, notes, etc)

The connector APIs are not hacks, they are defined APIs for people to extend the functionality of Outlook. You can also write your own MSMAPI protocol if you want to.

Comment: I was afraid of using the term 'de facto' ;-)  I just mean that it is a pretty popular protocol since most smart phones are using it today. That connector does not support versions of outlook after 2003.